# SSO from Magento to Salesforce

Tags: single-sign-on

We are implementing a site with 2 parts -

1. Magento Store and
2. Salesforce community. We want to implement a solution such that when a user registers and then signs in on Magento, and traverses any Salesforce related URL, he should not be prompted to login again for Salesforce. This means, user information from Magento should pass on to Salesforce.

Please help if anyone has implemented this kind of solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have Magento available to me, I can outline the general process. First, enable [IdP- and SP-initiated SAML for Magento](https://www.google.com/search?q=magento+saml) (some are free, others will cost you, but either way, you should get a read-me file to help out). Next, configure salesforce.com's [Single Sign On for Portals](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_portals.htm&language=en_US) feature, specifying the Identity Provider as Magento (exact steps will vary, consult the plugin's documentation). Finally, configure Magento's Single Sign On feature using the information from the salesforce.com configuration.